# Illustrator File Format Changes After Saving To A PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save, file-format, error

After I save an Illustrator file to a PDF format and then try to "autosave" the document, Illustrator saves it as a PDF instead of overwriting the .ai file. This causes problems for me because I save PDF's without editing capabilities, I would like to know if there is an automated way for Illustrator to save to an .ai file instead of overwriting the pdf.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the Illustrator file open and still save to a PDF make sure you do File -> Save A Copy...